# Google Assistant for voice-input game

Tags: actions-on-google

I'd like to develop a game/skill on Google Assistant that requires the following, once the user has entered the game/session (“hey Google, start game123”)

- playing an audio file that is a few minutes long
- playing a second audio file while the first clip is still playing
- always listening. While the files are playing, the game needs to listen and respond for specific voice phrases without the “Hey Google” keyword.

Are these capabilities supported? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"Maybe." A lot of it depends what devices on the Actions on Google platform you're looking to support and how necessary some of the requirements are. Depending on your needs, you may be able to play some tricks.

**Playing an audio file that is "a few minutes" long.**

You can play [audio using SSML](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/ssml#audio) that is up to 120 seconds long. But that will be played before the microphone is opened to accept a response.

For longer files, you can use a [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses#media_responses). This has the interesting feature that when the audio finishes, an event will be sent to your server, so you have some limited way to handle timed responses and looping. On the downside - users have to say "Hey Google" to interrupt it. (And there are currently some bugs when using it.)

Since you're doing a game, you can take advantage of the [Interactive Canvas](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas). This will let you use things such as the HTML `<audio>` tag and the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). The big downside is that this is only available on Smart Displays and Android devices - you can't use it on Smart Speakers.

**Playing multiple audio tracks**

Google has an extension to SSML that allows [parallel audio tracks](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/ssml#par) for multiple spoken and audio output. But you can't layer these on top of a Media Response.

If you're using the Web Audio API with the Interactive Canvas, I believe it supports multiple simultaneous inputs.

**Can I leave the microphone open so they don't have to say "Hey Google" every time.**

Probably not, but this may not be a good idea in some cases, anyway.

For Smart Speakers, you can't do this. People are used to something conversational, so they're waiting for the silence to know when they should be saying something. If you are constantly providing audio, they don't necessarily know when it is their "turn".

With the Interactive Canvas devices, we have a display that we can work with that cues them. And we can keep the microphone open during this time... at least to a point. The downside is that we don't know when the microphone is open and closed, so we can't duck the audio during this time. (At least not yet.)

**Can I do what I want?**

You're the only judge of that. It sounds like the Interactive Canvas might work well for your needs - but won't work everywhere. In some cases, you might be able to [determine the capabilities of the device the user is playing with](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/surface-capabilities#runtime_surface_capabilities) and present slightly different games depending on the features you have. Google does this, for example, with their "Lucky Trivia" game.

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed response. I will check out Interactive Canvas as it seems closest to my needs. Do you know if there is a plan for it to support smart speakers in the future?

As for leaving the microphone open, the use case is more like this: audio file #1 [background music] is always playing (looped 1 min clip is fine). The user says "jump!" or "fire!" and audio file #2 plays in response to the user [e.g. a boing sound or whoosh sound]